# Did Narasimha exist only for one and a half Muhurtas?

Tags: narasimha

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhurta

> In the Brāhmaṇas, muhūrta denotes a division of time: 1/30 of a day, or a period of 48 minutes.

In this discourse in Tamil, the speaker Dushyanth Sridhar says at 6:45 that the Avatara lasted only one and a half Muhurtas.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KrxURbR0Ig&t=5487s

Is there a scriptural basis for this?